# How do you add/edit attributes of input tag or class to DOM elements using php conditional statements?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a visual table reservation system and in order to signify that a certain table is booked, it will become disabled.

*the code is not done yet but I'm trying to figure out first how I can add properties using jQuery inside a php conditional statement**

php code:

```
<?php 
    include "php/dbconn.php";
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM place";
    $tables = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
    while ($tablesrow = mysqli_fetch_array($tables)) {
        $flag = false;

            #check muna kung walang schedule conflict
        $sql = "SELECT place FROM reservation WHERE status=0 AND (date='$date' AND starttime <= 
        '$endtime' AND endtime >='$starttime;')";
        $bookedresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($bookedrow = mysqli_fetch_array($bookedresult)) {
            if ($bookedrow["place"] == $tablesrow["id"]) {
                $flag = true;
                // echo $bookedrow["place"];
            }
        }
        if (!$flag) {
            // echo "<option>" . $tablesrow["id"] . "</option>";
            echo "<script>";`
```

`
Then the javascript inside (this is a continuation of php code) where I wish to add a disabled attribute to the input checkbox with id #tblc_1

```
$(window).load(function () {$('#tbl-c').attr('disabled', true);});
```

This is for the html checkbox

```
<div class="tbl-c-cont">
<div class="tbl-c tbl-c1">
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="tblc_1" value="tblc_1" name="tbl_id[]">
    </span>
</div>
<div class="tbl-c tbl-c2 ">
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="tblc_2" value="tblc_2" name="tbl_id[]">
    </span>
</div>
```

It doesn't work and I don't receive the achieved results.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you have written wrong selector here. it should be `#tblc_1` instead of `#tbl-c`. check updated snippet below

```js
$('#tblc_1').attr('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tbl-c tbl-c1">
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="tblc_1" value="tblc_1" name="tbl_id[]">
    </span>
</div>
<div class="tbl-c tbl-c2 ">
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="tblc_2" value="tblc_2" name="tbl_id[]">
    </span>
</div>
```